# GraphQL server returns a 422 Error when request sent from Android app via Apollo Client

Tags: android, spring-boot, graphql, apollo, graphql-java

Hi I've been trying to set up a simple Android app to send a query to a GraphQL server I set up on my localhost via Springboot. If I don't use the app to send a request, either through GraphiQL or Postman, everything is fine and I have absolutely no issues. It's only when I send the request in the app through an Apollo Client that I get a 422 error.

I've set up log statements in Springboot that hosts the GraphQL server to log the payload.

Here's the schema as defined in Springboot.

```
type Query {
  bookById(id: ID): Book 
}

type Book {
  id: ID
  name: String
  pageCount: Int
  author: Author
}

type Author {
  id: ID
  firstName: String
  lastName: String
}
```

Here's the query as defined in AndroidStudio for the Apollo Client to work with.

```
query BookById($id : ID) {
    bookById(id : $id){
      name
      author{
        firstName
        lastName
      }
}}
```

Here's the code in Android Studio.

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/graphql"; 
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private TextView textBox;
    private Button queryButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textBox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.plainbox);
        queryButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.queryButton);

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();

        ApolloClient apolloClient = ApolloClient.builder()
                .serverUrl(BASE_URL)
                .okHttpClient(okHttpClient)
                .build();


        // To make requests to our GraphQL API we must use an instance 
        // of a query or mutation class generated by Apollo.
        Input<String> id = Input.fromNullable("book-1");
        BookByIdQuery bq = BookByIdQuery.builder()
                                        .id("book-1")
                                        .build();

        queryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d(TAG, "REGISTERED CLICK");
                Log.d(TAG, "Book Query: " + bq.queryDocument());

                apolloClient.query(bq).enqueue(new 
                ApolloCall.Callback<BookByIdQuery.Data>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(@NotNull com.apollographql.apollo.api.Response<BookByIdQuery.Data> dataResponse){
                        Log.d(TAG, "Got Response: \n" + dataResponse.toString());
                        // changing UI must be on UI thread
                       textBox.setText(dataResponse.data().toString());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NotNull ApolloException a){
                        Log.d(TAG, "Failed, ApolloException " + a);                  
                    }
                });  // end apolloClient query
            }
        });
    }
```

Here's the log on the server side I get if making a request via GraphiQL or Postman.

```
DEBUG 13749 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.w.f.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter      : Before request [uri=/graphql]
```

Here's the log when the request comes from Apollo in the app.

```
DEBUG 13749 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.w.f.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter      : Before request [uri=/graphql]

DEBUG 13749 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.w.f.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter      : REQUEST DATA : uri=/graphql;payload={"operationName":"BookById","variables":{"id":"book-1"},"query":"query BookById($id: ID) {  bookById(id: $id) {    __typename    name    author {      __typename      firstName      lastName    }  }}"}]
```

Could the issue be related to the __typename attribute that Apollo is adding? Or could it be due to "id" being defined as a simple parameter in the server side schema but it being a variable in the Android Studio definition of the query?

I just expected to receive the response back with no issues since it seems to work every other way. Even if I type in the query manually into my web browser I have no issues getting the right response, it's only when working with Apollo Client in G̶r̶a̶p̶h̶Q̶L̶ Android Studio that this issue pops up and I'm at a complete loss as to why. I appreciate any help people can offer. Thanks in advance.

Update: So looking around some more it looks like when sending a query via ApolloClient it sends the query as an object instead of as a JSON string. Now I'm thinking that's probably the cause of the 422 error. I've also read that allowing my GraphQL server to accept objects in addition to JSON strings is something I must enable. I'm not really sure how to go about that though, so does anyone with experience with Spring Boot have any advice on how I could go about doing that? Thanks.